# difference between variables inside and outside of __init__() (class and instance attributes)

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

Is there any difference at all between these classes besides the name?

```
class WithClass ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = "Bob"
    def my_func(self):
        print(self.value)

class WithoutClass ():
    value = "Bob"

    def my_func(self):
        print(self.value)
```

Does it make any difference if I use or don't use the `__init__` method  for declaring the variable `value`?

My main worry is that I'll be using it one way, when that'll cause me further problems down the road.

Comment: A detailed answer with examples in the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056994/911945

Answer (score 359, accepted):

Variable set outside `__init__` belong to the class.  They're shared by all instances.

Variables created inside `__init__` (and all other method functions) and prefaced with `self.` belong to the object instance.

Comment: That's not what python does for me. Lists/dicts/etc get shared between all instances if you don't create them in `__init__()`.

Comment: @too much php: All variables at the class method (irrespective of mutability -- lists and dicts are mutable) are shared.  With immutable objects, the sharing isn't interesting.  With mutable objects (lists and dicts) the sharing is significant.

Comment: I suspected that might be the case but figured that if I stated my assumptions it might distract from the question itself, cheers for clearing it up :)

Comment: I figured this was what was happening, but it was very unclear to me.  Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I am a Python novice and I do not understand this reply by S.Lott.
Would somebody please clarify this a bit for us beginners?

Comment: What is the analogy of the variables created outside `__init__`? if those are shared by all instances, are modifying one of them affects all other instances?

Comment: No, just will change the new instances declared after the change. The existing instances will still have the old value for the variable

Comment: This is a bit misleading. A `varname`variable set outside the __init__ does belong to the class, and may be read via `self.varname` producing the same value for all instances. However, when assigned a value via an instance reference (as in `self.varname = X`)  a _new_ self.varname will be created _for that instance only_, obscuring the class variable. The class var remains reachable through a class reference (e.g: `WithClass.varname`). And class vars can also be set from any method by prefacing with the class name (`WithClass.myvar = X`) rather than an instance reference (`self.myvar = X`).

Comment: A variable set outside the __init __is called: 'Class Variable'. variable set inside the  __init__ is called: 'Instance Variable'.

Answer (score 136):

**Without Self**

Create some objects:

```
class foo(object):
    x = 'original class'

c1, c2 = foo(), foo()
```

I can change the c1 instance, and it will not affect the c2 instance:

```
c1.x = 'changed instance'
c2.x
>>> 'original class'
```

But if I change the foo class, all instances of that class will be changed as well:

```
foo.x = 'changed class'
c2.x
>>> 'changed class'
```

Please note how Python scoping works here:

```
c1.x
>>> 'changed instance'
```

**With Self**

Changing the class does not affect the instances:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 'original self'

c1 = foo()
foo.x = 'changed class'
c1.x
>>> 'original self'
```

Comment: note that this example works only for new type classes, with old ones, they will have the same result

Comment: @Abdelouahab, is that so? I tried it with old style classes, and got the same result as new style objects. Python 2.7.8

Comment: I think its important to note that as soon as you set foo1.x = ... the class variable 'x' is shadowed by the instance variable value 'x'.  If you change the Foo.x afterward, foo1.x will not be magically overwritten but has still the value of the instance variable.

Answer (score 53):

I would like to add something to the responses that I read in this thread and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python) (which references this one).

**Disclaimer**: this remarks come from the experiments I ran

**Variables outside `__init__`**:

These are, in fact, *static class variables* and are, therefore, accesible to all instances of the class.

**Variables inside `__init__`**:

The value of these *instance variables* are only accesible to the instance at hand (through the `self` reference)

**My contribution**:

One thing that programmers must consider when using *static class variables* is that they can be shadowed by *instance variables* (if you are accessing the *static class variables* through the `self` reference).

**Explanation**:

Previously, I thought that both ways of declaring the variables were exactly the same (silly me), and that was partly because I could access both kind of variables through the `self` reference. It was now, when I ran into trouble, that I researched the topic and cleared it up.

The problem with accessing *static class variables* through the 
`self` reference is that it only references the *static class variable* if there is no *instance variable* with the same name, and to make things worse, trying to redefine a *static class variable* through the `self` reference does not work because an *instance variable* is created which then shadows the previously-accesible *static class variable*.

To get around this problem, you should always reference *static class variables* through the name of the class.

**Example**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Foo:
    static_var = 'every instance has access'

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.instance_var = 'I am %s' % name

    def printAll(self):
        print 'self.instance_var = %s' % self.instance_var
        print 'self.static_var = %s' % self.static_var
        print 'Foo.static_var = %s' % Foo.static_var

f1 = Foo('f1')

f1.printAll()

f1.static_var = 'Shadowing static_var'

f1.printAll()

f2 = Foo('f2')

f2.printAll()

Foo.static_var = 'modified class'

f1.printAll()
f2.printAll()
```

**Output**:

```
self.instance_var = I am f1
self.static_var = every instance has access
Foo.static_var = every instance has access
self.instance_var = I am f1
self.static_var = Shadowing static_var
Foo.static_var = every instance has access
self.instance_var = I am f2
self.static_var = every instance has access
Foo.static_var = every instance has access
self.instance_var = I am f1
self.static_var = Shadowing static_var
Foo.static_var = modified class
self.instance_var = I am f2
self.static_var = modified class
Foo.static_var = modified class
```

I hope this is helpful to someone

Comment: This is the most important answer here

Comment: What I don't understand is why Python allow us to use self.a_variable_which_is_not_declared_in_the_constructor     Shouldn't be some type of error?

Comment: Well, there actually is a solution for that: `__slots__`. Among other things, using `__slots__` prevents adding new attributes.

Read more: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingSlots

Answer (score 6):

further to S.Lott's reply, class variables get passed to metaclass **new** method and can be accessed through the dictionary when a metaclass is defined. So, class variables can be accessed even before classes are created and instantiated.

for example:

```
class meta(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases,dicto):
          # two chars missing in original of next line ...
          if dicto['class_var'] == 'A':
             print 'There'
class proxyclass(object):
      class_var = 'A'
      __metaclass__ = meta
      ...
      ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class User(object):
    email = 'none'
    firstname = 'none'
    lastname = 'none'

    def __init__(self, email=None, firstname=None, lastname=None):
        self.email = email
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    @classmethod
    def print_var(cls, obj):
        print ("obj.email obj.firstname obj.lastname")
        print(obj.email, obj.firstname, obj.lastname)
        print("cls.email cls.firstname cls.lastname")
        print(cls.email, cls.firstname, cls.lastname)

u1 = User(email='abc@xyz', firstname='first', lastname='last')
User.print_var(u1)
```

In the above code, the User class has 3 global variables, each with value 'none'. u1 is the object created by instantiating this class. The method print_var prints the value of class variables of class User and object variables of object u1. In the output shown below, each of the class variables `User.email`, `User.firstname` and `User.lastname` has value `'none'`, while the object variables `u1.email`, `u1.firstname` and `u1.lastname` have values `'abc@xyz'`, `'first'` and `'last'`.

```
obj.email obj.firstname obj.lastname
('abc@xyz', 'first', 'last')
cls.email cls.firstname cls.lastname
('none', 'none', 'none')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a class comes with *member functions (methods)*, *class variables*, *attributes/instance variables* (and probably *class methods* too):

```
class Employee:

    # Class Variable
    company = "mycompany.com"

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, position):
        # Instance Variables
        self._first_name = first_name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self._position = position

    # Member function
    def get_full_name(self):
        return f"{self._first_name} {self._last_name}"
```

---

By creating an instance of the object

```
my_employee = Employee("John", "Wood", "Software Engineer")
```

we essentially trigger `__init__` that is going to initialise the *instance variables* of the newly created `Employee`. This means that `_first_name`, `_last_name` and `_position` are explicit parameters of the specific *`my_employee` instance*.

Likewise, *member functions* return information or change the state of a specific instance.

---

Now any variable defined outside the constructor `__init__` are considered to be *class variables*. Those variables are shared amongst all the instances of the class.

```
john = Employee("John", "Wood", "Software Engineer")
bob = Employee("Bob", "Smith", "DevOps Engineer0")

print(john.get_full_name())
print(bob.get_full_name())
print(john.company)
print(bob.company)

>>> John Wood
>>> Bob Smith
>>> mycompany.com
>>> mycompany.com
```

You can also use *class methods* in order to change the class variable for all the instances of the class. For example:

```
@classmethod
def change_my_companys_name(cls, name):
    cls.company = name
```

and now `change_my_companys_name()`

```
bob.change_my_companys_name("mynewcompany.com")
```

will have effect on all the instances of class `Employee`:

```
print(bob.company)
print(john.company)

>>> mynewcompany.com
>>> mynewcompany.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by S.Lott,

> Variable set outside **init** belong to the class. They're shared by
> all instances.
>
> Variables created inside **init** (and all other method functions) and
> prefaced with self. belong to the object instance.

**However**,
Note that class variables can be accessed via self.<var> **until they are masked by an object variable with a similar name** This means that reading self.<var> before assigning it a value will return the value of Class.<var> but afterwards it will return obj.<var> . Here is an example

```
In [20]: class MyClass: 
    ...:     elem = 123 
    ...:  
    ...:     def update(self,i): 
    ...:         self.elem=i  
    ...:     def print(self): 
    ...:         print (MyClass.elem, self.elem) 
    ...:  
    ...: c1 = MyClass()  
    ...: c2 = MyClass() 
    ...: c1.print() 
    ...: c2.print()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
123 123 
123 123 
In [21]: c1.update(1) 
    ...: c2.update(42) 
    ...: c1.print() 
    ...: c2.print()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
123 1 
123 42
In [22]: MyClass.elem=22 
    ...: c1.print()  
    ...: c2.print()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
22 1 
22 42
```

**Second note**: Consider [slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots). They may offer a better way to implement object variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
class foo(object):
    mStatic = 12

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "OBj"
```

Considering that foo has no access to x at all (FACT)

the conflict now is in accessing mStatic   by an instance or directly by the class .

think of it in the terms of Python's memory management :

12 value is on the memory and the name mStatic (which accessible from the class)

points to it .

```
c1, c2 = foo(), foo()
```

this line makes two instances , which includes the name mStatic that points to the value 12 (till now) .

```
foo.mStatic = 99
```

this makes mStatic name pointing to a new place in the memory which has the value 99 inside it .

and because the (babies) c1 , c2 are still following (daddy) foo  , they has the same name (c1.mStatic & c2.mStatic ) pointing to the same new value .

but once each baby decides to walk alone , things differs :

```
c1.mStatic ="c1 Control"
c2.mStatic ="c2 Control"
```

from now and later , each one in that family (c1,c2,foo) has its mStatica pointing to different value .

[Please, try use id() function for all of(c1,c2,foo) in different sates that we talked about , i think it will make things better ]

and this is how our real life goes . sons inherit some beliefs from their father and these beliefs still identical to father's ones until sons decide to change it .

HOPE IT WILL HELP

Comment: finding this answer helpful or not !! 
Try check this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ-VvGyQxho&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc&index=2

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
class inside:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []

    def insert(self, element):
        self.l.append(element)


class outside:
    l = []             # static variable - the same for all instances

    def insert(self, element):
        self.l.append(element)


def main():
    x = inside()
    x.insert(8)
    print(x.l)      # [8]
    y = inside()
    print(y.l)      # []
    # ----------------------------
    x = outside()
    x.insert(8)
    print(x.l)      # [8]
    y = outside()
    print(y.l)      # [8]           # here is the difference


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But if I use L to store an int, I can change the L even for the outside x, without changing the L of the outside y...

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy to understand if you track class and instance dictionaries.

```
class C:
   one = 42
   def __init__(self,val):
        self.two=val
ci=C(50)
print(ci.__dict__)
print(C.__dict__)
```

---

The result will be like this:

```
{'two': 50}
{'__module__': '__main__', 'one': 42, '__init__': <function C.__init__ at 0x00000213069BF6A8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, '__doc__': None}
```

Note I set the full results in here but what is important that the instance `ci` dict will be just `{'two': 50}`, and class dictionary will have the `'one': 42` key value pair inside.

This is all you should know about that specific variables.

Answer (score -1):

classes are like blueprints to create objects. Let's make a metaphor with building a house. You have the blueprint of the house so you can build a house. You can build as many houses as your resources allow.

In this metaphor, the blueprint is the class and the house is the instantiation of the class, creating an object.

The houses have common attributes like having a roof, living room, etc. This is where you **init** method goes. It constructs the object (house) with the attributes you want.

Lets suppose you have:

```
`class house:`
`roof = True`
`def __init__(self, color):`
`self.wallcolor = color`
```

`>> create little goldlock's house:`

```
>> goldlock = house() #() invoke's class house, not function

>> goldlock.roof

>> True

all house's have roofs, now let's define goldlock's wall color to white:

>> goldlock.wallcolor = 'white'
>>goldlock.wallcolor
>> 'white'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and check the difference

```
class test:
    f = 3

    def __init__(s, f):
        s.__class__.f = f
        s.f = s.__class__.f
        print(f'def __init__(s, {f})')
        print(f's.__class__.f = {f}')
        print(f's.f={s.__class__.f}')
        print(f'f={f}')
        print('===============init over===========')

    def setinstancetoOne(s, f):
        print(f'def setinstancetoOne(s, {f})')
        s.f = f

    print(f'class var f = {f}')

    def useClassname(test):
        print(f'>>>>def useClassname({test})')
        print(f'test.f {test.f}')

    def p_method(s):
        print(f'>>>>def p_method({s})')
        print(f's.f {s.f}')
        print(f'test.f {test.f}')
        print(f's.__class__.f {s.__class__.f}')

    print(f'class var f={f}')


# test.__init__.f = 19
t = test(2)
t.useClassname()
t.p_method()
print(f'Outside class t.f {t.f}')
print(f'Outside class test.f {test.f}')

print('______difference__________')
t = test(2)
t.setinstancetoOne(1)
t.useClass()
t.p_method()
print(f'Outside class instance variable(2) {t.f}')
print(f'Outside class class variable(3) {test.f}')
```