# correct way to define class variables in Python

Tags: python, class, attributes

I noticed that in Python, people initialize their class attributes in two different ways.

The first way is like this:

```
class MyClass:
  __element1 = 123
  __element2 = "this is Africa"

  def __init__(self):
    #pass or something else
```

The other style looks like:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__element1 = 123
    self.__element2 = "this is Africa"
```

Which is the correct way to initialize class attributes?

Comment: the diffence is not big if you use strings ... but it will get a complete different thing if you use dicts or lists that are stored by reference

Answer (score 744, accepted):

Neither way is necessarily correct or incorrect, they are just two different kinds of class elements:

- Elements outside the `__init__` method are static elements; they belong to the class.
- Elements inside the `__init__` method are elements of the object (`self`); they don't belong to the class.

You'll see it more clearly with some code:

```
class MyClass:
    static_elem = 123

    def __init__(self):
        self.object_elem = 456

c1 = MyClass()
c2 = MyClass()

# Initial values of both elements
>>> print c1.static_elem, c1.object_elem 
123 456
>>> print c2.static_elem, c2.object_elem
123 456

# Nothing new so far ...

# Let's try changing the static element
MyClass.static_elem = 999

>>> print c1.static_elem, c1.object_elem
999 456
>>> print c2.static_elem, c2.object_elem
999 456

# Now, let's try changing the object element
c1.object_elem = 888

>>> print c1.static_elem, c1.object_elem
999 888
>>> print c2.static_elem, c2.object_elem
999 456
```

As you can see, when we changed the class element, it changed for both objects. But, when we changed the object element, the other object remained unchanged.

Comment: but being __init__ always executed after the object is created, it becomes practically equal to define variables outside of __init__, right?

Comment: the big difference is that the static elements belong to the class, not to the object. I'll edit my answer with a little bit more explanation.

Comment: If you change a class attribute (one defined outside `__init__()`) it changes for the whole class. It will change for other instances too whereas instance attributes (defined in `__init__()`) are specific to each instance.

Comment: there might be a difference if you inherit from this class .. you could overwrite __init__() and don't call it on super.

Comment: I'd remove the double leading underscores in attribute names. They throw **AttributeError** (in my system at least). They invoke Python's name mangling according to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which means you'll have problems when subclassing. If you need to indicate they are private, just add a single leading underscore.

Comment: @chrisn654 I suggest you to read more about the Python name mangling, it's actually very interesting (not problematic)

Comment: This was very helpful. It's really important to understand that things outside __init__ are static. I did not realize this and it caused some very interesting results in my code. Unless you really want it to be static, just define everything inside __init__. I thought outside init was equivalent to inside init, They are VERY  different.

Comment: Thanks nitsas for the comment, It helps me to understand the "instance has no attribute" error message.

Comment: Not totally accurate:  `static_elm` changes for all class instances when assigned to via the class (`MyClass.static_element = X`), as shown. But when assigned to via a class instance, then, _for that instance_, `static_elm` will become an instance member.  If you do:   `c1.static_elem = 666`, then `print c1.static_elem, c2.static_elem` will produce `666, 999`. From within the class, `self.static_elm` returns `MyClass.static_elm` _until assigned_ `self.static_elm = X`. Then,  _a new_ `self.static_elm` is created, obscuring the class variable (still reachable through `MyClass.static_elm`)

Comment: Lobotomik made a clear explanation. Yes, that's a strange design on Python, it's very easy to confuse on this feature designed in Python, because the class element could be suddenly changed to be an instance's element.

Comment: @juliomalegria Perhaps an additional question on class variables. I noted that if a class is inherited, the derived class can add variables and they can be referenced by the base class with `self.inst_var`. However, if in the derived class, a class variable is defined, say `clas_var_deriv`. It can be only referenced by the base class as `self.clas_var_deriv`. Why is this the case? Kind of class variables of the the derived class become instance variables of the base class.

Comment: @Lobotomik: I believe it is only "shadowing" the class variable, since you can still access the unmodified class variable via c1.__class__.static_elem. Your words "static_elm will become an instance member" are understood by me in the sense that static_elem will change from class variable to instance variable. This is not the case.

Comment: I was so shocked when I kept getting an error because everythin seemed right and after two hours of looking i found out that i had __init__ as __inti__ !

Comment: As @gebbissimo mentioned, at the moment of initializing the c1.static_elem, the instance static_elem field is created on the fly which "shadows" MyClass.static_element static field in c1 instance. But static static_elem field does not accidentally change its status to being instance field and stays static, being accessible with c1.__class__.static_elem

Answer (score 23):

I think this sample explains the difference between the styles:

```
james@bodacious-wired:~$cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python

class MyClass:
    element1 = "Hello"

    def __init__(self):
        self.element2 = "World"

obj = MyClass()

print dir(MyClass)
print "--"
print dir(obj)
print "--"
print obj.element1 
print obj.element2
print MyClass.element1 + " " + MyClass.element2
james@bodacious-wired:~$./test.py 
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'element1']
--
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'element1', 'element2']
--
Hello
World
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print MyClass.element2
AttributeError: class MyClass has no attribute 'element2'
```

element1 is bound to the class, element2 is bound to an instance of the class.

Comment: I'm unable to edit or suggest edits. The output for `obj.element1` and `obj.element2` is messed up.