# PyQt QObject Unexpected Shared State

Tags: python, class, debugging, pyqt, qobject

I spent last night wrangling a particularly **confusing bug**.

I wrote some *proof of concept* code to exhibit the issue.

### PoC Code

```
# Standard Imports
import sys

# Import Core Qt modules
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject


class Bar(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent


class Foo(QObject):
    items = []

    def __init__(self, parent, item_count=2):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # Create some items
        for _ in range(item_count):
            self.items.append(Bar(self))

        # Debug
        print "QObject Foo Items: %s" % self.items
        print "QObject Foo Children: %s" % self.children()

# Start up main PyQT Application loop
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Build Foo classes
aFoo = Foo(app)
aFoo2 = Foo(app)

# Exit program when our window is closed.
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When this code is executed, here is the `output`:

```
QObject Foo Items: [<__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F078>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F0C0>]
QObject Foo Children: [<__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F078>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F0C0>]
QObject Foo Items: [<__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F078>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F0C0>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F150>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F198>]
QObject Foo Children: [<__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F150>, <__main__.Bar object at 0x0234F198>]
```

### Code Explanation

The code is creating two `Foo` QObject classes. Each class, during `__init__`, creates some `Bar` QObject classes and adds them to its class variable `self.items`.

The **bug** here is apparently when the second class prints out the items in its `self.items` class variable there are **four** and **not two** `Bar` classes in there.

### The Fix

If you move the class variable definition `self.items` into the `__init__` block of the `Foo` class, then things work fine.

### Thoughts

When `items` was defined outside of the `__init__` call it seems to act like a `Singleton` and share state across all `Foo` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question, I found the answer.

### Explanation

When the `items` variable in the `Foo` class was defined **outside** of the `__init__` call, the `items` variable became a **static** class variable.

Before were done though, there are some **gotcha** type situations due to how `mutable` and `immutable` objects work in Python that you should know about.

### Example Assignment

```
class Bar(object):
    aList = ["Hello World"]
    aString = "Hello World"

    def __init__(self, new=None):
        if new is not None:
            self.aList = new
            self.aString = new[0]

a = Bar()
print a.aList, a.aString
b = Bar(["Goodbye World"])
print a.aList, a.aString
print b.aList, b.aString
```

Here the class **static** variables are a `list` called `"aList"` and a `string` called `"aString"`. We created two `Bar` classes. The first class doesn't touch the static variables, but the second *does*. The second `Bar` class sets the static variables to new `objects` passed into the `__init__` call.

```
# Output
['Hello World'] Hello World
['Hello World'] Hello World
['Goodbye World'] Goodbye World]
```

This is very understandable output. The **static** variables were *not* changed on the class, as seen by the `["Hello World"] Hello World` printing *twice*. Instead, the second `Bar` class simply set its own `"aList"` and `"aString"` variables as a new `list` and `string` object in its class `self` object and this **overrode** the class' static variables for this specific `Bar` class causing us to see `["Goodbye World"]` instead.

### Example Modification

```
class Bar(object):
    aList = []
    aString = "A"

    def __init__(self, append=False):
        if append:
            self.aList.append('A')
            self.aString += 'A'

a = Bar()
print a.aList, a.aString
b = Bar(append=True)
print a.aList, a.aString
print b.aList, b.aString
```

Same as before but *instead* of setting the `"aList"` and `"aString"` variables to a new object we are simply concatenating onto them.

```
# Output
[] A
['A'] A
['A'] AA
```

**Uh oh! What happened?**

Our string class static variable `"aString"` came out **as expected**. We started it with just "A" and it stayed constant after the second instantiation of `Bar`. When the second `Bar` class print out its `"aString"` variable we saw "AA". This is due to the command `self.aString += 'A'`. This code takes the *current* value of `aString`, which is the `Bar` class static variable at this point, and appends another "A" before reassigning it to `self.aString` but **now** it is in the scope of `__init__` and is thus set in the class' `self` object and as we saw above this now overrides the static variable `aString` for this specific `Bar` class.

Our list class static variable came out **unexpected**. Instead of the same behavior as we saw with our string variable, our static list variable *changed* during the instantiation of the second `Bar` class. The change saw "A" added to our list object. The reason this happened is because unlike our static string object, when we execute `self.aList.append('A')` there is not re-assignment of the list variable into the executing class' `self` object. `append()` is accessing the list directly with no re-assignment. With no re-assignment there is no scope change to the static variable and thus no overriding will happen.

### Conclusion

The `string` object we saw in our examples is **immutable** in Python. When we appended to it, we were not adding to the `string` object in place. Instead, we were making a new `string` with an added character and then **re-assigning** our static variable to this new `string` object. This re-assignment coupled with being in the scope of `__init__` set the new `string` variable to the class' `self` object and overrode the static `string` variable altogether for the class.

The `list` object *is* mutable in Python. When we appended to it we *did* modify the `list` in place. Due to this, there was **no** re-assignment and the scope of the static variable did not change from being a static class variable. Due to this all changes to the variable are reflected in all classes as we saw in our examples.

### Links for More Reading

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python) question to learn more about **static** class variables in Python.

More information on **mutable/immutable** objects in Python can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python) and [here (external link).](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)