# Initialize a 2D Array in a Class in Python

Tags: python, class, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 3x3 Matrix class in python. I am having difficulty initializing the 2D array properly.

In the following code I am getting an error saying that Matrix3x3 has no attribute m. If I initialize m before the **init**, it seems like 'm' acts like a static variable, which I do not want.

```
class Matrix3x3:
    #[1 0 0]
    #[0 1 0]
    #[0 0 1]
    def __init__(self, m):
        #self.m[row][column]
        self.m[0][0] = m[0][0];
        self.m[0][1] = m[0][1];
        self.m[0][2] = m[0][2];

        self.m[1][0] = m[1][0];
        self.m[1][1] = m[1][1];
        self.m[1][2] = m[1][2];

        self.m[2][0] = m[2][0];
        self.m[2][1] = m[2][1];
        self.m[2][2] = m[2][2];
```

Comment: Dont add `m` as argument to init..just declare m within constructor

Comment: possible duplicate of [correct way to define class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: forget about `m` and just use `self.m =  [[0 for _ in xrange(3)] for _ in xrange(3)]`

Comment: Why on earth do you need this? Matrix and array solutions already exist, particularly see numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `m` needs to exist before you can set its elements, and even then, trying to set the value of an element in a list will fail if the list is too short. So

```
lst = []
lst[0] = 0
```

will fail but

```
lst = []
lst.append(0)
```

will succeed. `lst[0] = 0` should be thought of as trying to *change* the value of `lst` at index `0`, and can't be used if `lst` has no index `0`.

However, the simplest way to do what you want is either with list comprehensions,

```
class Matrix3x3:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = [[m[i][j] for j in xrange(len(m[i]))] for i in xrange(len(m))]
```

or with `deepcopy`, if you don't plan on altering the input:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix3x3:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.m = deepcopy(m)
```

Additionally, if this isn't for an assignment of some sort, you should consider instead using [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), which has a bunch of built in matrix operations, rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized that after looking at it for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:)

```
matrix_size = 3
Matrix = [[1 if x==y else 0 for y in xrange(matrix_size)] for x in xrange(matrix_size)]
```

Mayby is not 100% readeble at first, but works:)

Answer (score 0):

You must allocate m as a list of lists before setting its elements :

```
class Matrix3x3:
    #[1 0 0]
    #[0 1 0]
    #[0 0 1]
    def __init__(self, m):
        #allocate the lists : m is a list containing 3 lists of 3 None values
        self.m = [ [ None for j in range(3) ] for i in range(3) ]
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.m[i][j] = m[i][j];
```

or even better directly :

```
class Matrix3x3:
    #[1 0 0]
    #[0 1 0]
    #[0 0 1]
    def __init__(self, m):
        # directly init self.m
        self.m = [ [ m[i][j] for j in range(3) ] for i in range(3) ]
```

Comment: how does this create a list of lists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oups, used wrong braces : post edited

Answer (score -1):

This class will generate a matrix 3x3

```
class Matrix3x3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.m = []
        for item in range(3):
            self.m.append([0,0,0])


mat = Matrix3x3()
print(mat.m)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

it can be expanded upon to create X sized matrices

```
class Matrix_x_sized:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.m = []
        for item in range(x):
            self.m.append([0]*x)

mat2 = Matrix_x_sized(4)
mat2.m
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```