# Class attribute shadowing in Python class

Tags: python

I was learning [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function) to understand class attributes. But got confused with the output of following code snippet.

```
class A:
    aliases = None
    name = None

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.aliases = set([name])

    def add_aliases(self,a):
        self.aliases.add(a)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + str(self.aliases)

arr = []
for i in range(3):
    arr.append(A(i))
    arr[-1].add_aliases(i+1)

for item in arr:
    print item

A.aliases = set([]) ##Modify the static element of class
for item in arr:
    print item
```

Python Interpreter: 2.7.9

And output is

```
0set([0, 1])
1set([1, 2])
2set([2, 3])
0set([0, 1])
1set([1, 2])
2set([2, 3])
```

And I was expecting something like this as an output.

```
0set([2, 3])
1set([2, 3])
2set([2, 3])
0set([])
1set([])
2set([])
```

Comment: This can't be a duplicate as this question is trying to suggest that `always refer class attributes by class name to make your code easier to comprehend.`

Comment: you might wanna have a look at the answer i gave on the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the explanation is that when we write `self.aliases = set([])` we are actually *creating* a **new** instance attribute, *shadowing the class attribute*.

So, if we make our `__init__` function as follows we get the expected output.

```
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    A.aliases = set([name])  #using the class attribute directly
```

Also consider following code snippet:

```
class A:
    aliases = set([])
    name = None

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.aliases.add(name) # using the class attribute indirectly.

    def add_aliases(self,a):
        self.aliases.add(a)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + str(self.aliases)
```

Since in this case, we're **not** creating an *instance attribute*, there is no shadowing. And the test code in the question, would produce this output:

```
0set([0, 1, 2, 3])
1set([0, 1, 2, 3])
2set([0, 1, 2, 3])
0set([])
1set([])
2set([])
```

which is expected, as the class attributes are shared across all instances.

Here `A.alias` can also be referred as `self.alias` inside `init` or any other function. And since it did not shadow the static attribute, gave the expected output -- the case when all the the object share a common attribute.

A person not aware of this concept will not notice anything while using immutable data structure like `string` etc. But in case of data-structures like `list` and `dictionary` this may surprise.

Also consider following definition of `init`.

```
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name
    self.aliases.add(name) # referring to class attribute
    self.aliases = set([]) # creating a instance attribute
```

And this case also, it ended up creating `instance attribute` and output produced by test code is:

```
0set([1])
1set([2])
2set([3])
0set([1])
1set([2])
2set([3])
```

And form all this my learning is:

**Always refer class attribute with class name and instance attribute with object name, i.e. write `A.aliases` when you mean class attribute `aliases`, do not write `self.aliases` to indirectly refer `self.aliases`**

Comment: *"We, do not notice if we are using immutable data structure"* - really? I think most people would notice if their other classes weren't sharing the attribute they expected them to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well the linked question says so, I just added this question to supplement the two questions mentioned.

Comment: Then I think you've misunderstood the point the other questions were making about mutable vs. immutable class attributes. That's more to do with them sharing state when that *wasn't* expected, not not sharing state when it was.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I really did not notice this for very long.