# Python: passing url through variable not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, hp-quality-center

I've below code in python to connect to HP QC ALM and it's working as expected when values are hardcoded:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
class QC_ConnectorClass(object):
def __init__(self):
    print("class init")

def ConnectToQC(self):
    #HP QC OTA methods
    self.TD = Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection.1")
    self.TD.InitConnectionEx("http://hpqcurl.org")
    self.TD.Login("UName","Pwd")
    self.TD.Connect("Domain","project")
    if self.TD.Connected == True:
        print("Logged in")
        self.TD.Logout();
        print("Logged out")
        self.TD.ReleaseConnection();
    else:
        print("Login failed")
```

On passing hp qc url to variable like

```
hpQCURL="http://hpqcurl.org"
```

and pass the variable like this:

`self.TD.InitConnectionEx(hpQCURL)`

I receive the following error:

```
File "<COMObject TDApiOle80.TDConnection.1>", line 2, in InitConnectionEx
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147023174), None)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why it is downvoted?

Comment: I still wonder that why question is downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
class QC_ConnectorClass(object):
    var = "http://hpqcurl.org"
    def __init__(self):
        print("class init")    
    def ConnectToQC(self):
        #HP QC OTA methods
        self.TD = Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection.1")
        self.TD.InitConnectionEx(QC_ConnectorClass.var)
        self.TD.Login("UName","Pwd")
        self.TD.Connect("Domain","project")
        if self.TD.Connected == True:
            print("Logged in")
            self.TD.Logout();
            print("Logged out")
            self.TD.ReleaseConnection();
        else:
            print("Login failed")
```

Worked for me, but you can also initialize the variable globally outside the scope of the class. In this case I defined a static variable, that's why I need to call it in this way: QC_ConnectorClass.var
But take a look on this answer to understand the importance of the position of the initialization ([correct way to define class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python))

Comment: is there a way I can declare empty var and get the config value from .ini file on __init__ and pass the same in ConnnectToQC?

Comment: I found your answer helpful. I made a mistaken in .ini file. Since I am from .Net background, I pass values inside double quotes. So, I had like `url="http://url.org"` in .ini file. Actually, double quotes not required and has to be like `url=http://url.org`. It's fixed now. Thanks! Welcome to Stackoverflow!