# Calling a method which uses variables from another method in a class

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, maya

I'm writing a script in Maya and trying to assign a variable inside another method instead of inside `__init__` like we normally do. I put my window commands inside the `__init__` so when a new instance is initialized, if we assign variables inside `__init__` it will run all the way through without assigning the variables the value I want.

For example:

```
    def __init__(self, windowID = 'selectsomething', title = 'select something'):
        self.windowID = windowID
        self.title = title

        if cmds.window(self.windowID, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.windowID)
                    
        myWindow = cmds.window(self.windowID, title = self.title)
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns = 2, columnWidth = [(1, 300), (2, 100)],
                             columnAttach = [1, 'left', 10], columnSpacing = [1, 10],
                             rowSpacing = [1, 5])
        cmds.button(label = "Apply", command = self.applyButton) #it should print out selected object
        cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = self.cancelButton)
        cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

        #now for example if I have a sel variable to store selected objects, it would actually return nothing cuz the code ran all the way through and didnt wait for me to select what I needed
        sel = cmds.ls(selection = True) #this will return nothing
```

My solution is to assign variables inside the `applyButton` method, which will store what I selected. I found it's a bit weird to call a method which uses a variable from another method from that method itself.

For example:

```
class Abc:
    def func(*arg):
        print(self.var)
    
    def var(self):
        self.var = 1
        self.func()
        
abc = Abc()
abc.var()
```

For now the code runs, but doesn't it sound a bit weird to call the `func` method which uses the variable from `var` method from `var` method itself?

I haven't seen anyone do it. I mean without class, a variable assigned inside a function stays inside that function and we can only use it with `return`. But it looks like in class we can make any inside-method-variable global by adding `self.` before it?

My friend also said we can use `@property` in this case but I don't think I figured it out yet.

Comment: No, this isn't strange at all. This is the *whole point* of using a class, to encapsulate shared state. Note, it *isn't* global.

Comment: Hmm that does make me feel better, thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga. Can you explain a bit more on 'encapsulate shared state'? And btw, when you said 'it isn't global.' did you mean the variable actually belongs to the instance not the global? Thank you!!!

Comment: You are using a class method mixed with an instance variable what could be strange. e.g. if you do Abc().func() it will fail. But indeed, you can simply set an self.variable anywhere. In most cases I initialize it with None in the init and check if they are valid before I use them.

Comment: Didnt I use instance method? And thank you @haggikrey for your advices (y)

Comment: If you define a method like this func(args) in a class it will become a class method, an instance method is defined func(self, args) what you have done correctly in your var method.

Comment: @haggikrey No, a class method is defined if you decorate it with the `@classmethod` decorator.  `func(*arg)` is still an instance method; the invoking instance is just accessed via `arg[0]` rather than the name `self`.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thank you @chepner for pointing it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware that *data attributes* are implicitly a member of the class and can therefore be used by any method in the same class after they have been assigned somewhere.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects):

> Data attributes need not be declared; like local variables, they
>   spring into existence when they are first assigned to.

While your example will work (if you call `Abc.var()` before `Abc.func()`), it would IMHO be better style to initialize the variable at class level like this (note that I call it `val` to avoid confusion with the method name):

```
class Abc:
    val = 0

    def func(self, *arg):
        print(self.val)

    def var(self):
        self.val = 1
        self.func()
```

The purpose of the `self` keyword is nicely explained [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python).

Also note that initializing an attribute inside the `__init__` method will bind this attribute to a class instance, whereas initializing it outside of the `__init__` method will bind it to the class itself, which is a different thing (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python)).

Comment: Oh thank you so much @Gerd, I didn't notice that initializing an attribute inside and outside ```__init__``` can make a whole difference like that. And thank you for the info, helped me a lot!!!