# Access class method variable outside of class

Tags: python

I have this python class with a method and a variable in it:

```
class Main:
    def do_something(self):
        #does something
        x = 'something'
```

Is there a way to access the `x` variable outside of the class?

Comment: No, like any other function, `x` is local to that function. It ceases to exist after the execution of the function (of course, the *object* being referred to by that variable may or may not cease to exist, depending on whether it's still being referenced somewhere else). If you need data from a function, you should *return* that data. Alternatively, if you are using a method in a class, you could set that object to some attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, your existing code assigns `'something'` to `x`, but this `x` is actually not associated with the class instance. Change `x = 'something'` to `self.x = 'something'` does the trick.

```
class Person:
    def do_something(self):
        self.x = 'something'

person = Person()
person.do_something()

print(person.x)
# Prints 'something'
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056994/13095028) if you want to know more about the subtleties of initializing class variables.