# Python change dict value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, methods

I create a class with a dictionary variable, and a method for editing it:

```
class Test:
   TestDict = {"TestKey": "OldValue"}

   def ChangeDictionary(self):
       self.TestDict["TestKey"] = "NewValue"
```

Then, i create a two objects:

```
ObjectOne = Test()
ObjectTwo = Test()
```

Print their dictionaries before ChangeDictionary method call, and after:

```
# Print values before method call
print(ObjectOne.TestDict)
print(ObjectTwo.TestDict)

# Call method
ObjectTwo.ChangeDictionary()

# Print values after method call
print(ObjectOne.TestDict)
print(ObjectTwo.TestDict)
```

And i get this output:

```
{'TestKey': 'OldValue'}
{'TestKey': 'OldValue'}
    * * Method call * *
{'TestKey': 'NewValue'}
{'TestKey': 'NewValue'}
```

---

### So method ChangeDictionary which was called from second object changed value also and in first object.
Is it Python language bug or reasons of it somewhere else?

Updated:
If class variable will be any other type (For example - String) - In first object variable will have old value:

```
class Test:
    TestString = "OldValue"

    def ChangeString(self):
        self.TestString = "OldValue"
```

Comment: @tevemadar
If i get it right - No.
In topic which link you posted talks about changing variables of class from object.
My question is why dictionary value of object changing after i call a method from other object (Instanse of same class), if i will change variable type to any other (For example string) values will be stay different.

Comment: `TestDict` is shared across all objects since its not defined inside `__init__`. To fix this, create a `self.TestDict` and initialize it inside the `__init__` function. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Do mark the answer if it helped solve your question :)

Comment: @AkshaySehgal But why its all works only with dictionary?
If variable will have string type, after i change it - First object will have old value.

Comment: it works for all types of variables. please update the question (add the updated class) with the case that you are mentioning.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal question updated.

Comment: "Is it Python language bug" this should never be your first inclination for something like this, almost certainly, you are just not understanding something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in this top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056994/4755954):

- Elements outside the **init** method are static elements; they belong to the class.
- Elements inside the **init** method are elements of the object (self); they don't belong to the class.

To fix this behavior, try this -

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):                          #<-------
        self.TestDict = {"TestKey": "OldValue"}  #<-------
    
    def ChangeDictionary(self):
        self.TestDict["TestKey"] = "NewValue"
        
        
ObjectOne = Test()
ObjectTwo = Test()

# Print values before method call
print(ObjectOne.TestDict)
print(ObjectTwo.TestDict)

# Call method
ObjectTwo.ChangeDictionary()
print("** Method call **")

# Print values after method call
print(ObjectOne.TestDict)
print(ObjectTwo.TestDict)
```

```
{'TestKey': 'OldValue'}
{'TestKey': 'OldValue'}
** Method call **
{'TestKey': 'OldValue'}
{'TestKey': 'NewValue'}
```

EDIT: As mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga, modifications you are making with your class function are defining an immutable object separate from the one that you have before.

Note the different in the 2 methods below -

```
#### ORIGINAL STRING ####

class Test:
    TestString = "OldValue"

    def ChangeString(self):
        self.TestString = "NewValue"
        
        
ObjectOne = Test()
ObjectTwo = Test()

# Print values before method call
print(ObjectOne.TestString)
print(ObjectTwo.TestString)

# Call method
ObjectTwo.ChangeString()
print("** Method call **")

# Print values after method call
print(ObjectOne.TestString)
print(ObjectTwo.TestString)

print("** Self dicts **")
print(ObjectOne.__dict__)
print(ObjectTwo.__dict__)
```

```
OldValue
OldValue

** Method call **
OldValue
NewValue

** Self dicts **
{}
{'TestString': 'NewValue'}
```

AND, with `__init__`

```
### FIXED STRING ###

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.TestString = 'OldValue'
    
    def ChangeString(self):
        self.TestString = "NewValue"
               
ObjectOne = Test()
ObjectTwo = Test()

# Print values before method call
print(ObjectOne.TestString)
print(ObjectTwo.TestString)

# Call method
ObjectTwo.ChangeString()
print("** Method call **")

# Print values after method call
print(ObjectOne.TestString)
print(ObjectTwo.TestString)

print("** Self dicts **")
print(ObjectOne.__dict__)
print(ObjectTwo.__dict__)
```

```
OldValue
OldValue
** Method call **
OldValue
NewValue
** Self dicts **
{'TestString': 'OldValue'}
{'TestString': 'NewValue'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why is it works only with dictionary type variables?
If variable will be a string - Even if they will define ouside __init__ - They will changed only in their object.

Comment: "Variable set outside `__init__` belong to the class." Not exactly. Variables set in the class block *belong to the class*. Instance variables are any attribute you assign to an instance.

Comment: @KompTip no, no they won't. `str` objects *are immutable* so you cannot mutate them. You are probably *assigning another string* inside your method, which shadows your class variable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, updated language and added reference.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, so when we edit defiened out of ```__init__``` list/dictionary variable - We are change value of class variable, when we change a string variable value - We redefine/recreate it?

Comment: @KompTip no, the *type of the object is irrelevant*. If you assign a variable to `self` inside a method, i.e. the value of the first positional argument, that is assigning the attribute *to the instance*. Consider something like `class Foo: pass`, then if you do `foo = Foo(); foo.bar = 42` then you *created an instance variable*. That is **the exact same thing** that happens in a method, `def some_method(self): self.bar = 42`, `self` is just a naming convention, when you call `some_method` on an instance, the instance itself is passed as the first argument\

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Alright, big thanks.