# Is this python code thread safe (thread with twisted)?

Tags: python, multithreading, udp, twisted

I am writing an application to collect UDP messages and process them every 1sec.

Application prototype looks like:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import threading
import time

class UdpListener(DatagramProtocol):

    messages = []

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        self.messages.append(data)

class Messenger(threading.Thread):

    listener = None

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            recivedMessages = self.listener.messages
            length = len(recivedMessages)
            messagesToProccess = recivedMessages[0:length]
            #doSomethingWithMessages(messagesToProccess)
            del self.listener.messages[0:length]
            print(length)

listener = UdpListener()

messenger = Messenger()
messenger.listener = listener
messenger.start()

reactor.listenUDP(5556, listener)
reactor.run()
```

I am not sure if I can easily remove beginning values from list (del self.listener.messages[0:length]) without any risk that incoming message changes list and application crashes.

**Update** - version with lock

```
class Messenger(threading.Thread):

listener = None
lock = threading.Lock()

def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        recivedMessages = self.listener.messages
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            length = len(recivedMessages)
            messagesToProccess = recivedMessages[0:length]
            del self.listener.messages[0:length]
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
        finally:
            self.lock.release()

        #doSomethingWithMessages(messagesToProccess)
        print(length)
```

Comment: starting threads in twisted *usually* means you are doing something way wrong, which is the case here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe, no. You'd need to have a lock around `messages`.

However, you don't need a thread here. Why not do this?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class UdpListener(DatagramProtocol):
    callingLater = False

    messages = []

    def process(self):
        doSomethingWithMessages(self.messages)
        self.messages = []
        self.callingLater = False

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        self.messages.append(data)
        if not self.callingLater:
            reactor.callLater(1.0, self.process)
            self.callingLater = True

listener = UdpListener()

reactor.listenUDP(5556, listener)
reactor.run()
```

---

UPDATE: Here is how the original version would work with a lock, for educational purposes only. Note that this is not as efficient and also more prone to bugs. EDIT: Separated all the message logic out into `UdpListener` so the classes using it don't need to know its gooey internal details.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import threading
import time

class UdpListener(DatagramProtocol):
    message_lock = threading.Lock()
    messages = []

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        with self.message_lock:
            self.messages.append(data)

    def getAndClearMessages(self):
        with self.message_lock:
            res = self.messages
            self.messages = []
        return res

class Messenger(threading.Thread):

    listener = None

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            recivedMessages = self.listener.getAndClearMessages()
            length = len(recivedMessages)
            #doSomethingWithMessages(recivedMessages)
            print(length)

listener = UdpListener()

messenger = Messenger()
messenger.listener = listener
messenger.start()

reactor.listenUDP(5556, listener)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Just for improving my skills I added version with lock to "question" (us update). Could you tell me if now it is better?

Comment: @mrok: you would also need a lock around `.append(data)`, otherwise the lock isn't actually going to do anything. i've updated my post with what it would look like with lock (also with `with` notation instead of `try/finally`).

Comment: @mrok: also, np about `callingLater`. it's pretty neat indeed.

Comment: @Claudiu `.append()` is actually thread-safe (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568017/401656), at least in CPython. But I agree, I'd rather synchronize that call too (if forced to use locks, this is).

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement this with a DeferredQueue, which is exactly meant for this purpose. If you wish to use threads you need to take some extra care.

Here is an example with a DeferredQueue, allowing for threading:

```
class UdpListener(DatagramProtocol):

    def __init__(self)
        self._messages = DeferredQueue()

    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        self._messages.put(message)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def _wait_for_and_process_next_message(self):

        # Get message from queue through a deferred call from the DeferredQueue
        # Here we use @inlineCallbacks, so we assign the result from yield 
        # which is the new message, and will "block" (actually releasing control to Twisted) until a message gets in
        message = yield self._message_queue.get()

        # Do something with your message here, and ensure you catch any exceptions!
        # If your message processing may be long, you may wish to run it in another thread,
        # and because of @inlineCallbacks, this call will "block" until your function finishes.
        # In case you did this, ensure you read the notes below.
        yield threads.deferToThread(my_long_function, message)

        # Schedule an immediate call to this method again in order to process next message
        self.wait_for_and_process_next_message()

    def wait_for_and_process_next_message(self):
        reactor.callLater(0, self._wait_for_and_process_next_message)

    def initialize(self):
        # Call this during your application bootstrapping, so you start processing messages
        self.wait_for_and_process_next_message()
```

It is very important to note that in case you choose to defer your message processing to Twisted thread pool (using `threads.deferToThread`) your code will be running in a different thread. You'll be likely responding to messages from a different thread and, in Twisted, protocols are not thread-safe objects (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.2.0/core/howto/threading.html#auto0).

For this case you'd use `reactor.callFromThread()` to protect the critical resource `transport`, as in this example:

```
def _send_message_critical_section(self, message):
    self.transport.write(message, (self.host, self.port))

def send_message(self, message):
    reactor.callFromThread(self._send_message_critical_section, message)
```

Other changes done:

- Renamed the `messages` variable as `_messages`, as it should be considered entirely private.
- Moved the `_messages` initialization inside the `__init__()` method and assigned to `self._messages`, otherwise the messages list would be shared among all instances! I guess you had only one instance of the class but... ([Variables inside and outside of a class __init__() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function))