# Two Class instances in Python not different

Tags: oop, python-3.x, nidaqmx

I'm working on another data acquisition project, which has turned into an object oriented programming question.  In “main” at the bottom of my code I make two instances of the Object DAQInput.  When I wrote this, I thought my method .getData would refer to the taskHandle of the particular instance, but it does not.  When I run, the code does the getData task with the first handle twice, so clearly I don’t really understand object oriented programming in Python.  I’m sorry this code will not run without PyDAQmx and a National Instruments board attached.

```
from PyDAQmx import *
import numpy

class DAQInput:
    # Declare variables passed by reference
    taskHandle = TaskHandle()
    read = int32()
    data = numpy.zeros((10000,),dtype=numpy.float64)
    sumi = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    def __init__(self, num_data, num_chan, channel, high, low):
        """ This is init function that opens the channel"""
        #Get the passed variables
        self.num_data = num_data
        self.channel = channel
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.num_chan = num_chan

        # Create a task and configure a channel
        DAQmxCreateTask(b"",byref(self.taskHandle))
        DAQmxCreateAIThrmcplChan(self.taskHandle, self.channel, b"",
                                 self.low, self.high,
                                 DAQmx_Val_DegC,
                                 DAQmx_Val_J_Type_TC,
                                 DAQmx_Val_BuiltIn, 0, None)
        # Start the task
        DAQmxStartTask(self.taskHandle)

    def getData(self):
        """ This function gets the data from the board and calculates the average"""
        print(self.taskHandle)
        DAQmxReadAnalogF64(self.taskHandle, self.num_data, 10,
                           DAQmx_Val_GroupByChannel, self.data, 10000,
                           byref(self.read), None)

        # Calculate the average of the values in data (could be several channels)
        i = self.read.value
        for j in range(self.num_chan):
            self.sumi[j] = numpy.sum(self.data[j*i:(j+1)*i])/self.read.value

        return self.sumi

    def killTask(self):
        """ This function kills the tasks"""
        # If the task is still alive kill it
        if self.taskHandle != 0:
            DAQmxStopTask(self.taskHandle)
            DAQmxClearTask(self.taskHandle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myDaq1 = DAQInput(1, 4, b"cDAQ1Mod1/ai0:3", 200.0, 10.0)
    myDaq2 = DAQInput(1, 4, b"cDAQ1Mod2/ai0:3", 200.0, 10.0)
    result = myDaq1.getData()
    print (result[0:4])

    result2 = myDaq2.getData()
    print (result2[0:4])

    myDaq1.killTask()
    myDaq2.killTask()
```

Comment: Chances are that your shared objects (in class variables, e.g. `sumi`) are being munged (but I quickly stopped looking as the case is not minimal and the *symptoms* and expected behavior not been clearly described). See [Variables inside and outside of a class __init__() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These variables:

```
class DAQInput:
    # Declare variables passed by reference
    taskHandle = TaskHandle()
    read = int32()
    data = numpy.zeros((10000,),dtype=numpy.float64)
    sumi = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Are class variables. They belong to the class itself and are shared among instances of the class (i.e. if you modify `self.data` in `Instance1`, `Instace2`'s `self.data` is modified as well).

If you want them to be instance variables, define them in `__init__`.