# why using __init__ instead of coding directly at the class definition level?

Tags: python, class

The following code

```
class Myclass():
    print("from global")
    a = 1

    def __init__(self):
        print("from init")
        self.b = 2

x = Myclass()
print(x.a, x.b)
```

outputs

```
from global
from init
(1, 2)
```

What is the advantage of placing code which is executed when an object is created in `__init__` (`print("from init")` in the example above) instead of directly at the class level `(print("from global")`)?

Comment: I've never seen anyone put statements at class level, kinda surprised it works. Placing it in the `__init__` is useful for inheritance, and passing args to it.

Comment: Because there is such a thing as class-level attributes vs. per-instance attributes. `__init__` lets you access the instance as it is created.

Comment: Wrong flagged duplicate; correct duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function

Comment: @Evert: the other directly addresses this case. It is fine to create a little bit of a chain.

Comment: Hm, then the other isn't an exact duplicate; usual problem with closing questions as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the answers - as a side note it is interesting that the duplicates (and duplicates of duplicates) did not show up when I was searching. I revived the suggested duplicates but none of them were correct. I guess I should have done an explicit search instead.