# Why is db connection lost during multiprocessing when using a connection queue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a small suite of tests in Python that must interact with MySQL, and to speed up runtime I am using a multiprocessing `Pool` to map across CPU cores.

Each test instantiates an object containing functions to be tested. The object is also responsible for the initialization and lifecycle of its database connection, and it implements a cursor that queues connections:

```
class Cursor(object):
    _cache = Queue.Queue(maxsize=5)

    def __init__(self, cursor_type=mysql.cursors.Cursor, **options):
        super(Cursor, self).__init__()

        try:
            conn = self._cache.get_nowait()
        except Queue.Empty:
            conn = mysql.connect(**options)
        else:
            conn.ping(True)

        self.conn = conn
        self.conn.autocommit(False)
        self.cursor_type = cursor_type

    @classmethod
    def clear_cache(cls):
        cls._cache = Queue.Queue(maxsize=5)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor(self.cursor_type)
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, extype, exvalue, traceback):
        if extype is mysql.MySQLError:
            self.cursor.rollback()

        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.commit()

        try:
            self._cache.put_nowait(self.conn)
        except Queue.Full:
            self.conn.close()
```

When my tests were batched in a `Pool`, the process would always fail with this exception:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

I eventually narrowed down the disconnection problem to the queue (not the queue size, however - a queue size of 1 did not fix it). After removing the queuing-related parts of the `Cursor` object, multiprocessing is now stable.

I don't understand the why a connection queue would result in MySQL losing its connection. Since each process has a separate test object with its own (largely unused) queue, I wouldn't think it would interfere. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think you shouldn't be using using `self._cache`. Instead, use your cache as `self.__class__._cache`. This might be causing troubles after a call to `clear_cache`, where you create a new empty Queue. Your problem might be related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function)

Comment: @eventHandler Thanks for the link, and I think you are correct. I'm new to Python, and it was not clear to me that variables declared inside a class are static and global, making it not thread safe.