# How to define python member variables at compile time

Tags: python

Is there any way I can use to define member variables with default values other than defining them in `__init__` method?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function

Comment: If you want to do things at compile time, Python is not the language for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEP 557 -- Data Classes. (in python 3.7)
may be more to your liking
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/