# Why is datetime.now() set to a fixed moment in my module?

Tags: python, class, datetime, module

I am building a custom module (let's call it `test_mod`) for my files where I define a backup path with a timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Backup:
    Timestamp = datetime.now()
```

Using `import test_mod` and calling `test_mod.Backup.Timestamp` will return me the timestamp of the moment when the module was imported, but as I call the attribute again and again, the timestamp remains the same.

Why is that and what should I do if I want to make the `.Timestamp` atribute update whenever I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved the value of `datetime.now()` into an attribute. This means, that you called the method at the creation of the class instance and saved the return value into an attribute.

You should call `datetime.now()` inside a method / function if you want the timestamp to always be actual.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not a problem of your module instead of your class Backup.
You should put the initialization of Timestamp to the `__init__` method os your class.

This method is the initialization method of your class and is called every time you create a new object of type Backup.

```
class Backup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Timestamp = datetime.now()
```

I get different timestamps with this solution.

If you initialize a class variable outside the `__init__()` function the variable is shared by all classes and you get the same timestamp from each object of type Backup.

Link: [Variables inside and outside of a class __init__() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537202/variables-inside-and-outside-of-a-class-init-function)

When you want the current timestamp you could wrap the `datetime.now()` into a new function of your class Backup.

Comment: I do like this solution. But now let's say I have a method `test(self)` with `return 'a string' + str(self.Timestamp)`; it outputs a `TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` (using `str(Timestamp)` also gives this error), how should that be handled?

Comment: Could you post the whole class definition?
I can't the an problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use it as an attribute rather than a method i.e if you prefer Backup().Timestamp rather than Backup().Timestamp(), you should use @property

from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

```
class Backup:
    @property
    def time_stamp(self):
        return datetime.now()
```

to test it:

```
b = Backup()

print(b.time_stamp)
sleep(1)
print(b.time_stamp)
```

output:

```
2019-04-19 18:29:20.207778
2019-04-19 18:29:21.207825
```